# What's the default Spring 3 view resolver?

Tags: spring-mvc

I've read Spring 3 docs about view resolvers... But in my project I didn't define any. I just return a `ModelAndView` or `@ResponseBody` String from the controller methods. I guess there is a default view resolver (perhaps `UrlBasedViewResolver`) that is already configured. What is that? Where can I get info in the docs about this?

If I want to add other views like `JsonView` or `XmlView` (right now I use a Jsp that renders the data, but I read I can avoid this by passing model Objects directly to special views that will do this for me) how do I deal with this default view resolver?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default is an automatically-registered `InternalResourceViewResolver` (`UrlBasedViewResolver` is an abstract superclass of this).

If you declare your own view resolver(s), then the default `InternalResourceViewResolver` will not be used. You can, if you, wish, simply redeclare it as an explicit bean.  If there are multiple view resolvers, then they will be consulted in order until one of them returns a view object. However, because of the way that the servlet API works, `InternalResourceViewResolver`  must *always* be the last view resolver in the chain.

If your controller method returns a `View` object directly, then no view resolver is necessary, and the view will be rendered directly. Similarly, if you use `@ResponseBody`, the view resolver is bypassed.

Comment: You always know everything about Spring man... are you a spring developer? (Anyway thank you, I'm asking because I'm curious!)

Comment: @gotch4: No, just a long-suffering user :)

Comment: @skaffman, I haven't specified any view resolver in my {servletname}-servlet.xml file assuming "InternalResourceViewResolver" as default. But I am getting error `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LMS-MVC/userList] in DispatcherServlet with name 'lms'` Now if I configure this view resolver manually, it works. Can you please explain this behavior?

Comment: You amazing, amazing user: "Similarly, if you use @ResponseBody, the view resolver is bypassed."