# Spring & Thymeleaf: why use a ViewResolver implementation?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Why do Spring guide projects like [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) not have a class (such as in the example below) that implements Spring MVC ViewResolver interface? I have seen larger projects that do have this class, but it doesn't seem to be necessary with smaller ones.

At what point is it needed?

For instance, if I started with a project like the Spring guide project above and built it out, at what point would i need it?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

@Configuration
public class TemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        springTemplateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        springTemplateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: To put it another way, is there a default view resolver in spring if one is not explicitly included?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607598/whats-the-default-spring-3-view-resolver#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20default%20is%20an%20automatically,it%20as%20an%20explicit%20bean.). Did not see this when SO suggested answers to my question :(